# Compatibility problem between uBlock and proxy socks5 firefox addon

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, socks, adblock

To easily switch between my proxies, i use the addon "Proxy SwitchyOmega" for Firefox (https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/switchyomega/).
For several weeks now, the loading of websites is very slow, as if the loading is stuck in a standby/timeout status for 30sec-1min before accessing the website normaly.
After some research, it happens when SwitchyOmega and uBlock are both activated. If one of them are deactivated, everything works as usual (no slow loading).

Then i started experimenting with different version of uBlock and found that these slowdowns start happening with the 1.31.0 version of uBlock.
I know that SwitchyOmega is no longer maintained, but I'm only trying to find what causes this issue.

I'm using SwitchyOmega because it's the only one that fullfil all my needs.

Here is a result of Profiler Firefox during one of these slowdowns.
https://share.firefox.dev/3bX5fNI (the page used for this was https://mullvad.net/servers/)

My Firefox is up to date and uBlock settings are by default.

Thx in advance for enlighting me on this :)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to set cnameUncloak to false in the advanced settings of uBlock Origin.
It's all good now.